# Is that possible to steal the message sent by Intents?

Tags: android, android-intent

**Update:**
I have spent more than 2 hours to google, but I can't find the answer. I've add a main.java the handle the activity send from the Login Activity. Now the file tree looks like:
[image]

But still got error

> E/AndroidRuntime(1282): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No
>   Activity found to handle Intent {
>   act=com.goodboy.loginIntent.action.main
>   cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] (has extras) }

I know this question is simple, I am new to android, any help would be appreciated:)

Android allows for Intents that have specific recipients(the Activity or Service) as well as Intents that are broadcast throughout the system to any components that may be listening.

I want to make a PoC(Proof of Concept) that if we do not set setClassName, others can listen your private message.

This PoC is simple, suppose there is Login Activity for App Goodboy, when a user put his username and password in the login activity, and click the login button, the evil activity from App Badboy steal the this message.

However, failed:(

When I click the login button, failed:
[image]

And the evil intent got nothing:

[image]

The java source code of Login Activity

```
package com.goodboy.loginIntent;
import com.goodboy.loginIntent.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
public class GoodloginActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText et_user;
    private EditText et_pwd;
    private Button btn_login;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        et_user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_user);
        et_pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pwd);
        btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent m_intent = new Intent();
                m_intent.putExtra("username", et_user.getText().toString());
                m_intent.putExtra("password", et_pwd.getText().toString());
                m_intent.setAction("com.goodboy.loginIntent.action.main");
                m_intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                startActivity(m_intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The source code of main.java

```
package com.goodboy.loginIntent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.goodboy.loginIntent.R;
public class main  extends Activity {
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }
}
```

The login layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_user"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_pwd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The java source code of evil activity:

```
package com.badboy.stealIntent;

import com.badboy.stealIntent.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BadIntentActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "username: "+this.getIntent().getStringExtra("username")+
                "\npassword: "+this.getIntent().getStringExtra("password"),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Thanks @David Wasser, the manifest of login app(**update**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.goodboy.loginIntent"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".GoodloginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".main"
            android:label="@string/main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The manifest of the badIntent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.badboy.stealIntent"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".BadIntentActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Post stacktrace in logcat please.

Comment: Post also your manifest (for both apps)

Comment: @DavidWasser thank you:) I just added the manifest files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably getting an `ActivityNotFoundException` when you call `startActivity()` in `GoodloginActivity` because there is no Activity known to the system that responds to:

```
ACTION = "com.goodboy.loginIntent.action.main" and
CATEGORY = CATEGORY_DEFAULT
```

Have a look at your logcat output.

Comment: Thanks David, I have tried to add a new java file to response the Login Activity, but failed:(

Comment: You need to tell Android which Activity to start when you call startActivity() with your ACTION and CATEGORY. You need to add an intent filter to your manifest for the activity that you want started. Intent filter looks like this: <intent-filter> <action android:name="com.goodboy.loginIntent.action.main" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> </intent-filter>

Comment: Also, you can't have 2 activities in your manifest that have an intent filter with ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER, because then when you start your app from the home screen, Android doesn't know which activity to start.

Comment: I modified the intent-filter to <intent-filter> <action android:name="com.goodboy.loginIntent.action.main" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> </intent-filter>, but got error:No Launcher activity found!

Comment: What about your good login activity? Doesn't that have CATEGORY=LAUNCHER?

Comment: Thanks again:)Now I modified my inten-filter to:<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.goodboy.loginIntent.action.main" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter> . And "No Launcher activity found!" once again:(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12540/discussion-between-liweijian-and-david-wasser)

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [Intent Intercept](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.ashtonbrsc.android.intentintercept&hl=en), an application aimed for developer which, as the name says, intercept any "public" Intent, allowing you to browse the intent setup and data. Intent Intercept is Open source, you can browse the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/intrications/intent-intercept)

As for your problem, check that the BadBoy application is registered for the action you're using. Also, take a look at the stacktrace in logcat on goodlogin to see where the activity crashes.